# linking error for libs in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In my project exist two sub project.

main project is shopGUI
other ones are 'connection' and 'log'
I build at first a log.lib file from log project
then add it to connection project and build connection.lib

then I try use connection in main project(shopGUI) but I have linking error.
error said that in

connection.lib(Client.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall log::print....."

thanks herzl

Comment: You don't link the library that implements `log::print...`. Check that, (1) the log.lib implement this, (2) you link with that library. You can enable "Show Progress" at the linker settings to see detail. BTW: The complete error message might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libraries don't link in dependent libraries.

You'll need to link your ShopGui with both sub project libraries.

Comment: But ShopGui don't use log at all ?

Comment: But does connection.lib use log.lib?

Comment: yes use log.lib and contain it.I found the problem, the problem was that I do

Comment: I'm not sure however, that a .lib can contain another .lib because I don't think there's actually any linking going on when you create a .lib.

Comment: the problem was that I didn't build log.lib peropr.when tried your answer system show other problem that I forget a dll file then I understand my mistake.I built a log.lib that use DLL

Comment: Ah ok. I'm glad to hear you've got it sorted!

Answer (score 1):

Possibilities:

1) You linked improperly
2) You have forgotten to define (write the body of) log::print

Comment: I impelemented log::print 
what is my mistake?
why my linking is improperly?

Comment: @herzl: Then you haven't linked properly to the lib. How did you do the linking ?

Comment: 1) I copy the lib file where that exist project file 2) add it to (link/librarian)->input->Additional dependencies.
then build the project.

Comment: @herzl: In this case I don't know what the problem is, sorry